# PermanentWriteProtect of SDCard's CSD

Tags: embedded, sd-card

On an embedded system, I use and SD card.

One of the card has turned the PermanentWriteProtect bit ON (in the CSD register).

I could'nt find any info on the net, why the SD card controller turned this bit ON, how to avoid it ?

I guess there's no way to turn it OFF back ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Does the SD card you are using have write protect enabled.  If you orient the SD card so the connector is on top, there is a slide switch on the left side of the card.  It must be in the up position.  If it is the down position that card is write protected.

Comment: This is unlikely to have anything to do with the question asked.  The "write protect" switch is merely a piece of plastic, it has no connection to the card internals whatsoever.  The intent is that the position of the plastic is detected by a leaf switch in the host, and then the **host software** *chooses* to refuse writes.  There is no hardware protection involved, and given that the asker is talking about specific card registers, they are hopefully aware of what their software is doing.